# Determine Cu+2 and SO4-2 concentration using Potentiometry?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, titration, concentration

The title says it all. I've been researching as well but all I could come close was solid state ion selective electrodes. Could someone please help me out?

There should be two methods(or one) to measure the concentrations.

Comment: What's wrong with electrodes?

Comment: You certainly need electrodes to measure a potential, like a [potentiometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometry) for a [potentiometric titration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentiometric_titration). (While Copper is better measured via [photometrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photometry_(optics)) and sulphate by [gravimetrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravimetric_analysis))

Answer (score 3):

What is the range of the components? This is very important because this will determine if titration or photometry is used (or a combination of both).

Also interfering components should be known. For eaxample. Barium is known to react with a lot of other components ([solubility table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solubility_table)). Also EDTA reacts with oter components (Also depending on the pH ([EDTA complexation constants](http://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/courses/cem262/EDTATable.html))

**Titration:**

Copper and sulfate can be determined in one analysis using and copper ISE. This is done by adding an NH3 buffer (pH of solution = 10) and adding an exxess of Barium nitrate. Barium will react with SO4 and the free barium is titrated. Titrate the solution with EDTA. This first inflection point will be copper, the second one the free barium.

Keep in mind that EDTA reacts with a lot of other components. Also if the concentration difference (molar) between copper and barium is large, high titrant usages are to be expected

**Photometry:**

Copper can be determined using an variaty of chemical substances (e.g. cuprizone, Bathocuproine). The choise depends on range, interfering components ect..

Sulfate is possible. However, titration is preferred.

Comment: @Tharindu Any progress on the application?